# Localizing string with special characters in razor view

Tags: razor, localization

I need to display localized text that has special characters. For example "and/or" an "company's". I have the translated strings in my resource bundle, but only the default English is ever displayed. if I remove the '/' and apostrophe, the translated text displays. Unfortunately, I don't have the power to change the text, so I need to figure out how this is done. All pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found the answer. I need to provide the appropriate escape sequences before the character that needs to be escaped. In my case, the apostrophe needed to be replaced with ' and the '/' needed to have the an escaped '\' before it, \